# Creating HTML table with foreach

Tags: php

I am trying to build table with results from database.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_prijavljeniupis ',OBJECT);
```

then i am trying to make table in this way

```
echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo  '<tr>';
    echo '<th>UID<th>';
    echo '<th>ID<th>';
    echo '<th>Ime<th>';
    echo '<th>Prezime<th>';
    echo '<th>JMBG<th>';
    echo '<th>Telefon<th>';
    echo '<th>Adresa<th>';
    echo '<th>BrojUlice<th>';
    echo '<th>PttBroj<th>';
    echo '<th>Grad<th>';
    echo '<th>Drzava<th>';
    echo '<th>Grad<th>';
    echo '<th>Odsek<th>';
    echo '<th>NacinPlacanja<th>';
    echo '<th>NacinSkolovanja<th>';
    echo '<th>kampanja<th>';
    echo  '</tr>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    foreach ( $results as $result ) 
    {    

        echo '<td>'.$result->UID.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->ID.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Ime.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Prezime.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->JMBG.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Telefon.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Adresa.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->BrojUlice.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->PttBroj.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Grad.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Drzava.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Odsek.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->NacinPlacanja.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->NacinSkolovanja.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->Kampanja.'</td>';



    }

     echo '<tbody>';

     echo '</table>';
```

I am not sure how to implement tr in my tbody part, because i have loop, i try diffrent options but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `<tr>` in start of the loop and `</tr>` at the end

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo  '<tr>';
echo '<th>UID<th>';
echo '<th>ID<th>';
echo '<th>Ime<th>';
echo '<th>Prezime<th>';
echo '<th>JMBG<th>';
echo '<th>Telefon<th>';
echo '<th>Adresa<th>';
echo '<th>BrojUlice<th>';
echo '<th>PttBroj<th>';
echo '<th>Grad<th>';
echo '<th>Drzava<th>';
echo '<th>Grad<th>';
echo '<th>Odsek<th>';
echo '<th>NacinPlacanja<th>';
echo '<th>NacinSkolovanja<th>';
echo '<th>kampanja<th>';
echo  '</tr>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tbody>';


foreach ( $results as $result ) 
{    
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->UID.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->ID.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Ime.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Prezime.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->JMBG.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Telefon.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Adresa.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->BrojUlice.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->PttBroj.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Grad.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Drzava.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Odsek.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->NacinPlacanja.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->NacinSkolovanja.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Kampanja.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';


}

 echo '</tbody>';

 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You have `echo '<\tbody>';` it's `echo '</tbody>';`

Comment: @VladimirŠtus The person who answered made a few syntax errors and I fixed them. One of which being `echo '</tr>` which should have been `echo '</tr>';` - Reload the answer/code and try it again.

Comment: @Fred -ii i told you error its not in sintax, i try that already, i wrote "I am not sure how to implement tr ", please delete question

Comment: @VladimirŠtus I am **not** the person who answered. Look at the name under "answered.... minutes ago".

Comment: @VladimirŠtus what you would see and what you got? Can post screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You added extra column in table head 
echo 'Grad';
there should be equal number of columns for both table head (thead) and table body (tbody) tags, then only your table will be well aligned.

try this code

```
echo '<thead>';
echo  '<tr>';
echo '<th>UID</th>';
echo '<th>ID</th>';
echo '<th>Ime</th>';
echo '<th>Prezime</th>';
echo '<th>JMBG</th>';
echo '<th>Telefon</th>';
echo '<th>Adresa</th>';
echo '<th>BrojUlice</th>';
echo '<th>PttBroj</th>';
echo '<th>Grad</th>';
echo '<th>Drzava</th>';
echo '<th>Odsek</th>';
echo '<th>NacinPlacanja</th>';
echo '<th>NacinSkolovanja</th>';
echo '<th>kampanja</th>';
echo  '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

foreach ( $results as $result ) 
{    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$result->UID.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->ID.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Ime.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Prezime.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->JMBG.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Telefon.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Adresa.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->BrojUlice.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->PttBroj.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Grad.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Drzava.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Odsek.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->NacinPlacanja.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->NacinSkolovanja.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result->Kampanja.'</td>';
    echo "</tr>"


}
  echo '</tbody>';
 echo '</table>';
```